# Newton ring can be used to measure the surface tension coefficient of liquid?

Tags: optics, surface-tension

I don't quite understand the principle of Newton's ring. I want to know whether Newton's ring can be used to measure the surface tension coefficient of liquid

Comment: [Newton's rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings) is an experiment to demonstrate interference in light. Do you mean the [du Noüy ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_No%C3%BCy_ring_method).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I recently participated in the physics experiment innovation competition held by our country. I am interested in the liquid surface tension. I guess whether Newton's ring can be used for the measurement of liquid surface tension. Because I have a short time to study physics, I don't have a special understanding of Newton's ring. After consulting some information, I feel it is not feasible, so I asked. Now I think this method should not be feasible. I need to think about other aspects.